# script login me devuelve a mi pagina

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo un script para hacer login que estoy cambiando de mysql a mysqli.
La cuestión es que en mysql funciona todo normal pero en mysqli al hacer el login me devuelve a la misma pagina.
He añadido el mysqli errno pero no me arroja ningun error (a lo mejor lo estoy aplicando mal) y hace lo mismo.

Este seria el script.

login.php:

```
include 'conexion.php';
if ($_GET['logout'] == '1'){
setcookie ("svgsrevsid", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("svgsrevskey", "", time() - 3600);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(true);
}

if(isset($_POST['nusuario']) && !empty($_POST['nusuario'])){
$usuario = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nusuario']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['paswd']);
$cookie = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cookie']);
$consulta = "SELECT usrid, passwd, rango, nombre, estado FROM usuarios     WHERE nusuario='$usuario'";
$result= $con->query($consulta);
$row = $result->fetch_array();
if(is_numeric($row['usrid'])){
    $passactual = $row['passwd'];

if(password_verify($password,$passactual) && $row['estado'] === 'activo'){
        $_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION['SKey'] = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
        //$_SESSION['IPaddress'] = ExtractUserIpAddress();
        $_SESSION['LastActivity'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; 
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['usrid'];
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['rango'] = $row['rango'];
        if (isset($_POST['cookie'])){
            $consulta2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET cookie = '".$_SESSION['SKey']."' WHERE usrid = '".$row['usrid']."'";
            $do=$con->query($consulta2);
            setcookie("svgsrevsid", $row['usrid'] , time()+(60*60*24*365), "", "" );
            setcookie("svgsrevskey", $_SESSION['SKey'] , time()+(60*60*24*365), "", "" );
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['request']) ){
            if ($_SESSION['rango'] === 'empleado'){
                header('Location: ./selprogram.php');
            }else{
             $_SESSION['cliente'] =  $_SESSION['user'];  
             header('Location: ./equipos.php');
            }
        }else{
            header('Location: '.$_SESSION['request']);
        }
    }  
}
```

Aparentemente el codigo parece estar bien, quizas al cambiar de mysql a mysqli deba cambiar el orden de ciertos parametros.

Espero me puedan aroojar un poco de luz en este reves, GRACIAS por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hola Dan, bienvenido! Para poder ayudarte mejor iría bien saber qué error se produce. ¿podrías incluir un ejemplo del resultado que devuelve cada una de las queries en este código? De paso te pregunto: No recibes ningún error php ni hay errores en el log?

Comment: edit: PD: se que deberia implementar mayor seguridad pero primero quiero hacer que funcione y despues pasar a implementar mayor seguridad con las consultas preparadas.

Comment: no recibo ningun error, el script al hacer login deberia redireccionarme a la pagina que corresponde si eres user, cliente o empleado. Si no pones nada te devuelve a la pagina login.php y si los datos son incorrectos me da un aviso de que son incorrectos. la parte que me funciona es la de datos incorrectos que si pones un user que no esta en la BD te da el error sin embargo si pones datos correctos o no pones nada te envia a login.php

Comment: ¿Hacia donde está redirigiendo? Haz una depuración de todas las variables con las que estás trabajando con `var_dump` así como con la variable de sesión y revisa los datos comprobando que están correctos, que ninguno es nulo, vacío, etc. También, sería bueno cerrar `$result` una vez obtenidos los datos, para que no haya problemas cuando vayas a mandar otras llamadas a `query`, pues no conviene que haya otros recursos abiertos.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de revisar durante horas el codigo descubri que el error no estaba en el archivo de login si no en el de conexion en el que deje comentada la linea para abrir la sesion y usar la variable superglobal $_SESSION.

conexion.php

```
<?php 
$con= new mysqli("127.0.0.1","user","pass","bd");  
if ($con->connect_errno > 0)
{
die('Could not connect [' . $con->connect_error. ']');
}
session_start() //tenia esta linea comentada de ahi el error
?>
```

espero les ayude a otros principiantes como yo. Saludos :)